# Estimating largest $k$ such that that norm([v1,v2,..,vk])<2 for random normalized vectors $v$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-matrices, descriptive-statistics, concentration-of-measure

Suppose I sample $k$ vectors from normal distribution, centered at $0$ and with covariance $\Sigma$, then normalize them to have norm $=1$, and finally stack them as rows in a data matrix $X_k$.

I'd like to determine how big I can make $k$ such that $\|X_k\|<2$ with probability $p\approx 0.5$

Are there results that can help me determine such $k$ from easily computable properties of $\Sigma$?

Empirically on toy problems, it seems $k\approx 3*\text{intrinsic dimension}(\Sigma)$ defined as $\frac{\text{Tr}(\Sigma)}{|\Sigma\|}$.

[image]

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/fb-stable-rank-batchsize.nb)

Motivation: this helps determine largest batch size for which "linear learning rate scaling" works for batch-SGD on normalized linear least squares problems.

Comment: Can you specify what norm you use for $||X_k||$?

Comment: Using operator norm